# How can i get latest new mail using Mailcore2 Api?

Tags: ios7, mailcore2

I am new bie in IOS developement.I am stuck in this problem
I am using Mailcore2 api in my ios app.I want to get the new emails which are recently coming in Inbox.
Here is my Code
In ViewDidLoad method..

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSUserDefaults *defaules = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *emailid = [defaules objectForKey:@"emailid" ];
NSString *password = [defaules objectForKey:@"password" ];

session = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];
session.hostname = @"imap.gmail.com";
session.port = 993;
session.username = emailid;
session.password = password;
session.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeTLS;
MCOIMAPIdleOperation *idle=[session idleOperationWithFolder:@"INBOX" lastKnownUID:64];
[idle start:^(NSError *error)
{
NSLog(@"finished checking account.");
if (error) {
NSLog(@"ERROR-%@",error);
}
else
{
NSLog(@"DONE");
[self fetchemail:10 folder:@"INBOX"];
}
}];
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
[idle interruptIdle];
NSLog(@"HELOO");
});
}
```

by this method all the emails are loaded when the view is load.
I have use MCOIMAPIdleoperation to get latest emails but it is not working.
but latest email is not fetched.

Please Help to get over it..

Comment: You need to use -[MCOIMAPSession fetchMessagesByUIDOperationWithFolder:requestKind:uids:] to fetch messages.

Comment: I have used this but still new email is not fetched...I have confusion about the uid parameter what parameter should be passed in the uid???

Comment: You should pass the range of messages to fetch: MCORangeMake(1, MAX_UINT64)

Comment: Please take a look at the examples on the repository.

Comment: Thanks for reply Sir,I had also used MCORangeMake(1,MAX_UINT64).but it does not works for me..

Comment: Could you copy-paste connectionLogger logs in a gist and include a link to the gist in the description?